# My imagewand raises an exception on 2nd run of while loop

Tags: python, image, pdf, ocr, wand

I am writing a script which converts PDF to Image for an OCR to read to then rename the PDF. It then deletes the converted image after the task has been executed. Since OCR is not 100% correct, I would loop it around with a different setting and compare the new file name with a masterlist. The problem is that it runs fine the first run, but it is not able to loop. I get this exception raised

I am confused as the correct PDF file name has been relocated and the images have been deleted so no duplicates should occur but the error raised is asking for the file which has already been relocated to another folder.

```
def find_ext(dr, ext):
    return glob(path.join(dr,"*.{}".format(ext)))

allpdf = find_ext(".","pdf")



def TwoLine():
   for PDF_file in allpdf:
      PDFfile = wi(filename=PDF_file[2:],resolution=200)
      Images = PDFfile.convert('jpg')
      width,height = Images.size
      Images.crop(0, 0, width, height//3) 
      Images.scale(scaledef,1000)
      Images.sharpen()
        # Images.enhance()
        # Images.auto_orient()
        # Images.auto_level()
      ImageSequence = 1
      imagefile = PDF_file[2:-4]+str(ImageSequence)+".jpg"
      Images.save(filename=imagefile)
      for img in PDFfile.sequence:
         Image = wi(image = img)
         ImageSequence += 1
         pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
         photo=cv2.imread(imagefile)
         text = pytesseract.image_to_string(photo)
         text_file=open("Notepad.txt","w+")
         text_file.write(text)
         text_file.close()
         text_file= open("Notepad.txt","r+")
         notes=text_file.readlines()
         counter=0
         name=""
         for line in notes:
            line=line.replace("["," ")
            line=line.replace("]"," ")
            numbers=sum(c.isdigit() for c in line)
            letters=sum(c.isalpha() for c in line)
            spaces=sum(c.isspace() for c in line)
            line=line.strip("\n")
            line=line.strip("\t")
            line=line.replace("|"," ")
            others=len(line)-numbers-letters-spaces 
            if numbers>=5 and others<2 and counter<2:
                line=line.replace("SN"," ")
                cond_pass_fail = 1
                if counter ==0:
                    if line[0]=="_":
                        line=line.replace("_","",1)
                    line=line.replace('=','')
                    name+=line
                    if len(name)>=12:
                        os.rename(PDF_file, name +".pdf")
                        break
                    counter+=1
                elif counter ==1:
                    name+="_"
                    name+=line
                    if "__" in name:
                        name=name.replace("_","",1)
                    counter+=1

            elif counter>=2:
                try:
                    os.rename(PDF_file, name +".pdf")
                    counter=0
                    break
                except FileExistsError:
                    continue

        else:
            fail_lst.append(PDF_file)
            print("Cant find name in " + PDF_file)
        
    os.remove(imagefile)
def PNFilter():
   FileList=[]
   for files in allpdf:
      PN=files.split('_')[0]
      PN=PN.replace('.\\',"")
      masterfile=open("masterfile.txt","r")
      master=masterfile.readlines()
      for line in master:
        line=line.strip("\n")
        line=line.strip("\t")
        if PN not in line:
            continue
        elif PN in line:
            FileList.append(files)
            break
   path=r'C:\\Users\\khairilamir.binahmad\\Desktop\\PDFRENAME\\test\\'
   for files in allpdf:
      if files in FileList:
        source=path+files
        dest=path+"PNFilter"
        shutil.move(source,dest)

while bool(allpdf)==True and scaledef>=2500:
    scaledef-=100
    TwoLine()
    PNFilter()
```

Error that appears in terminal:

```
File "c:\Users\khairilamir.binahmad\Desktop\PDFRENAME\test\AllLine.py", line 175, in <module>
    TwoLine()
  File "c:\Users\khairilamir.binahmad\Desktop\PDFRENAME\test\AllLine.py", line 47, in TwoLine
    PDFfile = wi(filename=PDF_file[2:],resolution=200)
  File "C:\Users\khairilamir.binahmad\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 9144, in __init__
    self.read(filename=filename)
  File "C:\Users\khairilamir.binahmad\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 9815, in read
    self.raise_exception()
  File "C:\Users\khairilamir.binahmad\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\wand\resource.py", line 222, in raise_exception
    raise e
wand.exceptions.BlobError: unable to open image 'A51357_2135721090100.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3536
```

Comment: Hi, i have edited to include more relevant information. As im not sure where is the root cause of error, i might have included too much. Would appreciate if you could help. Thanks

Comment: `allpdf` just contains file names, without a path.  You need to specify the path when you open the file in TwoLine.  And remember they've all been moved by then.

Comment: I have added into the post regarding the function that I used to collect file names. I am new to python and am not quite sure what you mean. The file moving occurs after the first full run of TwoLine. It moves the ones that are successful, thus I would thought that only the failure files would remain in the folder. The error that shows up is for the successful file which has already been moved to another folder.

Comment: So, the indentation in your code above is wrong, in `PNFilter`?  Can you fix that, please?

Comment: Apologies for the wrong input. I have corrected the indentation issue in the post, which is now following the script I have.

Comment: OK, you fetch the list of files.  You do a conversion.   You then move all of those files to a subdirectory.  So when you call `TwoLine` again, none of the files are there any more.  What is `PNFilter` supposed to be doing?

Comment: TwoLine converts PDF to images, which OCR reads and then converts the names. I cannot get the OCR to work 100% of the time, so with PNFilter, I compare all the files it has converted its name to with a masterfile note. Then it moves ONLY the files which is already correct to a subdirectory. The files which are incorrect would remain in the main folder. Then the loop SHOULD occur and TwoLine would repeat itself but with a different setting, and it repeats until there is no file in the main folder.However due to the error raised, no loop is done. Hope that clears any misunderstanding, thank you.

Comment: But you don't re-create `allpdf`, so whatever files you move in `PNFilter` will be gone from the file system but their names are still in `allpdf`, and that will cause `TwoLine` to get the error you are seeing.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. So I have to call allpdf again in the loop so as to reset it to fetch only the current files in the mainfolder. Thank you for your help :)